# Does unique convex combination imply affine independence?

Tags: vector-spaces, affine-geometry, convex-hulls

[Why we need affine independent to ensure the unique representation of a vector from convex hull](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2148252/1287431). As far as I understood, the converse of the theorem is not true. In other words, if any vector  is in the convex hull of $\mathbb{M}$, can be written as a unique convex combination of the vectors in $\mathbb{M}$, then can we say the vectors in $\mathbb{M}$ are affinely independent? What can be a counterexample?